# GLEW and GLFW on Windows 10 for Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, windows-10, glfw, glew

I have just downloaded GLEW (glew-2.1.0-win32) and GLFW (glfw-3.3.8.bin.WIN64) but I don't know what I should do with these files once they are downloaded so that they are recognized in Visual Studio Code (version 1.75.1). Where should I integrate them? Do I have to modify anything? If yes, how?

I tried to integrate some of the GLEW and GLFW files in my compiler folder C:\msys64\mingw64

Visual Studio Code was able to recognize the #include<GL/glew.h> and #include<GLFW/glfw3.H> but it didn't recognize the syntaxes "drawCircle()", "updateWindow()", "isWindowOpen()", "pollEvents()" or "isKeyPressed()"

Comment: You need some sort of make system. A popular one is cmake. You'll probably find some good examples online with glew and glfw. Personally, I think that Visual Studio is better suited for C++ dev than Visual Studio Code. With Visual Studio, you don't need a make system like cmake (although I'd recommend something like Premake if you want to publish your project), but you still have to add glew and glfw to the additional include directories and link the static libraries. If you end up going for Visual Studio, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OR4fNpBjmq8) should help.